# Earth's magnetic field lines with magnetic compass needle

Tags: magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

Will the compass needle deflect in the opposite side inside the earth?
If so, where will be that location inside the earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interior of the earth is too hot to support ferromagnetism but some articles I've read suggest that as the liquid iron core at the center of the earth cools, some parts solidify.   The heat of fusion from this process heats the surrounding liquid, causing it to circulate.  The loops of circulating liquid metal interact with any existing magnetic field, setting up a feedback mechanism which enhances the field. From our point of view, this process appears to be stable, but we do know that over long periods of time the field can reverse direction. Currently the field resulting from (perhaps many) such dipoles emerges from the earths southern hemisphere and dives back into the northern. The dip of the field, from the horizontal, depends on the latitude, going from zero near the equator to 90 degrees near the poles.  It would pass back through the iron core going from north to south. (The north magnetic pole is near the south geographic pole.)